# What causes "member reference base type 't_list *' is not a structure or union"?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working with linked lists and I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void            *content;
    struct s_list   *next;
}   t_list;
```

I was trying to make a function that swapped first 2 elements and tried this:

```
void sa(t_list  **a)
{
    if (!*a && !*a->next)
        return ;
}
```

And it gave me the following two errors:

```
member reference base type 't_list *' (aka 'struct s_list *') is not a structure or union gcc
expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type but it has type "t_list **" C/C++(132)
```

However if I do this:

```
void sa(t_list  **a)
{
    t_list  *t;

    t = *a;
    if (!*a && !t->next)
        return ;
}
```

It works. Why is this? What am I missing?

Comment: @xing What is the difference between the two? Why does the second one work?

Comment: Whenever you are wondering why an extra pair of `()` has any effect, it is time to go back to your C text book (or google) and check operator precedences again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence. `->` has higher operator precedence than unary `*`. Hence "expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type but it has type "t_list **", because the compiler tries to apply `->next` on a `t_list**` type.

Fix: `(*a)->next`.

Comment: Btw the second example is recommended practice - whenever dealing with pointer to pointers, then don't "drag the pointer to pointer syntax around". Use a temporary plain pointer as in the example, the first thing you do. Makes the code easier to read and prevents bugs such as this one.

Comment: Similarly given some `void alloc (blabla** x)`, then don't do plain ugly things like `*x = malloc(sizeof **x * n);`. Do `blabla* tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp * n); ... *x = tmp;`.